# Import bpmn file in bonitasoft

Tags: bonita

I have any question, in bonitasoft can you load or read a model in bmpn file? I found in the API Rest and Engine Api to bonita documentation and not found any information about this.

Thanks!

Comment: You can import the BPMN model in our Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to import a BPMN 2.0 file format in Bonita BPM Studio. Go in the `Diagram` -> `Import` menu, select `BPMN 2.0`in the input format list and click on the `Browse...` button to select your *.bpmn file.

You can find more information about import and export capabilities of Bonita BPm Studio in the [official documentation](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/import-and-export-process-1).

Comment: Thanks for you response, but i need import this about code , not this visual interface in bonita.

Comment: Sorry but your need is not really clear to me. Can you try to describe your use case a little bit more?